# Алгоритм сложения длинных чисел

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Создаю свой класс больших чисел BigInteger. Число представляю как массив(вектор) цифр+знак. Для примера смотрю код из другого класса. Не могу понять, как работает алгоритм оператора += в данном случае, зачем здесь три похожих цикла?

P.S. BASE=10.

```
BigInt BigInt::operator+=(const BigInt &A){
short both;
if( coef.size() <= A.coef.size() )
    both = coef.size();
else
    both = A.coef.size();

short carry( 0 );
short i;
for(short i=0; i<both; ++i ) 
{
    short val = coef[i] + A.coef[i] + carry;
    coef[i] = val % BASE;
    carry = val / BASE;
}
for( ; i<coef.size(); ++i ) 
{
    short val = coef[i] + carry;
    coef[i] = val % BASE;
    carry = val / BASE;
}
for( ; i<A.coef.size(); ++i ) 
{
    short val = A.coef[i] + carry;
    coef.push_back( val % BASE );
    carry = val / BASE;
}
if( carry > 0 ) coef.push_back( carry );
return *this;}
```

Comment: Второй цикл добавляет перенос к числу this в случае, если coef.size() < A.coef.size(). Третий добавляет старшие разряды A.coef и перенос в случае, если A.coef.size() > coef.size(). Обратите внимание, что во втором и третьем цикле отсутствует инициализация `i=0;`, т.е. значение `i` остаётся после первого цикла

Comment: А как грамотно модифицировать, чтобы убрать три цикла, оставив 1? :С

Comment: @Xerocry, не нужно их убирать. 

Выполняется только один из них в случае, когда в A и coef *разное* количество цифр. И он работает с еще не обработанными цифрами более длинного числа.

Comment: Спасибо, кажется разобрался!

Comment: @avp можно и убрать. Делать первый цикл до по слагаемому максимальной длины. Правда тогда придётся добавлять if'ы/условные выражения, чтобы не учитывать более короткие слагаемые, но так тоже можно

Comment: @alexlz, конечно с if внутри цикла сделать можно, но менее эффективно.

Comment: Зачем модифицировать алгоритм, если ты не понимаешь как он работает?

Answer (score 0):

Из трёх циклов выполняются только два. Первый отвечает за само сложение чисел, а второй копирует более длинное число в результат при необходимости добавляя к нему перенос. Вторых циклов в коде 2 для двух случаем - когда первое число длиннее и когда второе длиннее.

Вот перевёрнутый пример (числа записал в привычном виде, а не как в коде задом наперёд):

```
  123456789 - this
       1111 - A
---------------
  ?????7900 - первый цикл
  12345     - второй цикл
            - третий цикл
---------------
  123457900
```

```
       1111 - this
  123456789 - A
---------------
  ?????7900 - первый цикл
            - второй цикл
  12345     - третий цикл
---------------
  123457900
```